# Error 403 Access Denied - EspoCRM import

Tags: php, csv, http-status-code-403, espocrm

I just did a fresh install of EspoCRM and while trying to import Leads from Administration>Import, I face issue of 403 Access denied.
As per the official docs, I have set the proper permissions for all directories. Still facing the issue.

Can someone help?

Comment: 403 means forbidden. You might not set the roles properly. Go to Administration > Roles. Check `espocrm/data/logs` folder for logs.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you asking question related to espocrm in espo https://forum.espocrm.com for quick answers from creators of this project.